# Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use') in Vue.js router configuration

Tags: javascript, vue.js, error-handling, vue-router, web-development-server

Description:
I am working on a leaderboard web application using Vue.js. After completing my code, I attempted to launch the server on localhost, but encountered an error. The error message I received is as follows:

```
Uncaught runtime errors:

ERROR
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use')
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/router.js:10:45)
    at ./src/router.js (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:79:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:203:33)
    at fn (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:436:21)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/main.js:4:65)
    at ./src/main.js (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:69:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:203:33)
    at http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1324:109
    at __webpack_require__.O (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:249:23)
    at http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1325:53
```

I tried creating a new project to fix the error, but the problem persists. I also made sure to repeatedly install both Vue and Vue Router, but that didn't resolve the issue. I am seeking assistance in identifying and resolving the problem.

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";

import Scoreboard from "./components/ScoreboardTable.vue";
import Submissions from "./components/SubmissionDetails.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  { path: "/scoreboard", component: Scoreboard },
  { path: "/submissions/:problemId", component: Submissions },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

The objective of this project is to develop a single-page app for viewing a competition's scoreboard. The app should have two pages: the Scoreboard page and the Submissions page, each serving a specific purpose.

I appreciate any assistance in locating and fixing the issue. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which Vue version are you using? This is Vue 2 setup, if you actually use Vue 3, you'd probably get an error like the one you are seeing

Comment: ├─┬ @vue/cli-plugin-babel@5.0.8
│ └─┬ @vue/babel-preset-app@5.0.8
│   ├─┬ @vue/babel-preset-jsx@1.4.0
│   │ └── vue@3.3.2 deduped
│   └── vue@3.3.2 deduped
├─┬ vue-router@4.2.0
│ └── vue@3.3.2 deduped
├─┬ vue@3.3.2
│ └─┬ @vue/server-renderer@3.3.2
│   └── vue@3.3.2 deduped
├─┬ vuetify@3.2.4
│ └── vue@3.3.2 deduped
└─┬ vuex@4.1.0
  └── vue@3.3.2 deduped

Answer (score 2):

You are using Vue 3, but instantiate vue-router as you would have in Vue 2 (`Vue.use(...)`)

With Vue 3, you create the router with `createRouter()` and add it to the app instance (instead of a global Vue object):

```
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from 'vue-router'

const routes = [...]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  routes,
})

const app = Vue.createApp({})
app.use(router)
```

The [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/) has more details.